# Hide a column when fetch the all data in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I want to list all users data from the database in PHP. there will be a user is logged-in at a single time. I want un-fetch or hide a single row who has active(logged-in).  so, I'm asking you how can I do this...

```
$query=$conn->pdo->exec("SELECT * FROM usertable");   
$row=$query->fetch();

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Post</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($row=$query->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo ucfirst($row['name']); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucfirst($row['user_type']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: which column keeps track of user login?

Comment: @AlivetoDie but Sir, I have to get all the data that has been added later.

Comment: This code is not PDO. Or it doesn't work

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP has columns and rows heavily confused in their mind. Hence the question.

Comment: Codes are not important here, it is an example only, it is based on query builder. I can't upload every code here.

Comment: @AlivetoDie sorry i mean row.

Comment: try this:- `$query=$conn->pdo->exec("SELECT * FROM usertable where  <column name>  != <active value>");` . change column name and it's corresponding value to skip those rows

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes bro its working, thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

You can add new field in your usertable like logged with default value 0.when user login you should change 0 to 1.Now you change your sql query `**select * from usertable where logged='0';**`